# PTKView subview in swift

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement `PTKView` subview in swift for Stripe authorising cards. 
I am getting an error of :

```
reason: 'Can't add self as subview'
```

this is my code in swift

```
import UIKit
class PaymentViewController: UIViewController , PTKViewDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var PaymentView : PTKView
        var view : PTKView = PTKView(frame: CGRectMake(15,20,290,55))

        PaymentView = view
        PaymentView.delegate = self;
        view.addSubview(PaymentView)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added self.view.addSubview(PaymentView)
and it did the trick